# SQL Query To update the specified cell

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Table name - Masterdata

Column name - geofencepolygon

I need to update the value stored in the geofencepolygon column.

The value stored is "POINT(77.5133514404297 13.0273038762366)".

I need to update the value to "POINT(13.0273038762366 77.5133514404297)".

Like this, i have around 20 rows. I need to perform the same operation for all the rows

Is it possible to update the value like this from sql query?. If Yes.. Please suggest a way to do it

Thanks

Comment: SQL has many useful types of queries. One such is `UPDATE`

Answer (score 1):

If you know the previous value of geofencepolygon.

```
UPDATE TABLE `Masterdata` SET `geofencepolygon` = 'POINT(13.0273038762366 77.5133514404297)` WHERE `geofencepolygon` = 'POINT(77.5133514404297 13.0273038762366)'
```

Alternately, if this field is NOT a unique or primary key, you should pass the key value in the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You need a query like this:

```
UPDATE Masterdata  
SET geofencepolygon = 'POINT(13.0273038762366 77.5133514404297)' 
WHERE geofencepolygon = 'POINT(77.5133514404297 13.0273038762366)';
```

Regards.